# Clear div before appending/overriding div with ajax

Tags: jquery

I am trying to override a "display panel" panel div, based on selected table row. On click the display panel div updates with an image associated with the selected table row.

ie. selecting table>td.id 1 = display pane displays image 1 if selecting td.id 2 = display pane displays image 2.

```
  var userImage; // works pulls image data in the ajax
  var uid; // selected tr id's or single 
   for(var i = 0; i < uid.length; ++i)
  {
  //display preview pane if overlay type is selected
  // if 1 useris selected remove and override the current users image displayed
  if ( uid.length == 1){
    $(".user-holder").html('<div class="previewer">'+
    '<div class="inner-edit">'+
    '<div>'+userImage+'</div>'+
    '</div>'+
  '</div>');
  }
  //if multiple users are selected
  if ( uid.length > 1)
  {
    $(".user-holder").append('<div class="previewer">'+
    '<div class="inner-edit">'+
    '<div>'+userImage+'</div>'+
    '</div>'+
  '</div>');
  }
}
```

When selecting single divs, they override the preview, but the issue I am trying to trying to get to work, when multiple ids are selected override the previously selected, and append with the multiple selected ids.

TIA

Comment: `$(".user-holder").html()` just clear it like this when `uid.length` is greater  > 1. If will clear all the existing HTML and append the new ones.

Comment: hi @AlwaysHelping i had tried this it still keeping the previously selected user image, when i try one of the below examples $(".user-holder").html(''); it returns only one even though i have selected multiple ids

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the content in many different ways:

`.html('')` replace the HTML content as empty string

`.text('')` replace the text content as empty string (if your `div` contains only text, but works for HTML too)

`remove()` remove the elements from the DOM (have to be applied to the child element)

```js
$("#clean").click(function(){
  $("#id1").html('');
  $("#id2").text('');
  $("#id3 *").remove();
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="id1"> 
  <div>
  blablabla 1
  </div> 
</div>

<div id="id2"> 
  <div>
  blablabla 2
  </div> 
</div>

<div id="id3"> 
  <span>
  blablabla 3
  </span> 
  <span>
  blablabla 3
  </span> 
  <span>
  blablabla 3
  </span> 
</div>


<button id="clean">Clean</button>
```